# libary control for Xpages and using ssjs for defaultvalues/validators

Tags: jsf, xpages, xpages-extlib

I' working on a libary control for Xpages and need some help in creating.

I would create an control wich reads a configuration file and creates controls in a table, controls like Editboxes, checkboxgroups and so on.
Ive Build my control like Keith Strickland
in his Bolg entry 
http://xprentice.gbs.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=82770C11FA7B9B21852579C100581766

so and now to my queststion:

I would store in my configuration ssjs code for computing a defaultvalue or an validation
but how could I compute the ssjs?

the automatic generated code from the Designer uses a PageExpressionEvaluator Object but I couldent create one by my self.

someone an Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ExpressionEvaluatorImpl class instead:

```
com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl( facesContext )
```